# How does linearity of a measurement imply that the commutator of all measured observables are $c$-numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, measurement-problem, commutator, observables

I really don't understand with the linearity conditions I have where this comes from.

Comment: What do you mean by linearity conditions? $[L_x, L_y] = i\hbar L_z$